# What software to cast a .mp4 with subtitles?

Tags: google-chrome, vlc, mp4, chromecast

I have a .mp4 and a .srt for English subtitles. I would like to play my video and cast it to Chromecast. What software should I use?

On Google Chrome, I am able to Chromecast it but the subtitles are not displayed.

On VLC the subtitles are displayed but I could not find a cast option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromecast has these restrictions:

> Your subtitle resources must implement CORS.
>
> - TTML - Timed Text Markup Language
> - WebVTT - Web Video Text Tracks
> - CEA-608/708

None of the regular players supports it.

You can use [castnow](https://github.com/xat/castnow). It is a 3rd party tool, not available in the repositories and it is a command line player. You can do it like this:

```
   castnow --address '192.168.1.X' {file} --subtitles {subs}
```

Installation requires npm so:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

and

```
sudo npm install -g castnow
```

Comment: How do I know the IP adress of my Chromecast 192.168.1.X?

Comment: check the wifi connection

Answer (score 0):

## Gnomecast

https://github.com/keredson/gnomecast

## Subtitles

Chromecast only supports a handful of subtitle formats, .srt not included. But it does support WebVTT. So we extract whatever subtitles are in your video, convert them to WebVTT, and then reattach them to the video through Chomecast's API.